# Solution/project structure for building Lua in Visual Studio 15 community

Tags: c++, lua, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build Lua in Visual Studio 15 community. [This Lua documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html) says I should have three "projects" (in a generic sense), one for the library, one for the interpreter, and one for the compiler. I'm not a real expert at Visual Studio, and I'm new at Lua. So how should this be structured in Visual Studio?

Comment: [Useful video for beginners](https://youtu.be/X5D_h2X8LCk)

Comment: Very sharp video but, in my world, building without an IDE project or makefile, or even a batch file, goes against the grain. But, @Gerard, does that or [LuaBinaries](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/) get you to where want to start?

Comment: I have not had a chance to carry out the steps in the video, but it looks promising. I would be unhappy about the lack of an IDE if I were working on the development of the Lua compiler or interpreter, but since I'm just a user, I don't care about an IDE. Thans for LuaBinaries; the binaries I found were out of date.

Comment: Check out http://blog.spreendigital.de/2015/01/16/how-to-compile-lua-5-3-0-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the makefile I use.  It works with either Microsoft's NMAKE or Borland's MAKE.  You will need one additional download from Lua's website:
https://www.lua.org/extras/5.3/one.tar.gz

```
################################################################################
# MSVS/Borland makefile for Lua
################################################################################

LUA = lua
LUAC = luac
VC = /vc/bin/cl.exe -O1 -I.

################################################################################
# You will need to have the one.c file from the Lua website, inside here:
# https://www.lua.org/extras/5.3/one.tar.gz
#
# Assuming prior execution of the following Win CLI scripts, example:
# \vc\vcvarsall.bat
#
# UPX is an optional step for compressing the final binaries

all:
  $(VC) -DMAKE_LUA -Fe:$(LUA) one.c
  $(VC) -DMAKE_LUAC -Fe:$(LUAC) one.c
  $(VC) -DMAKE_LIB -LD -Fe:lua53.dll one.c
  @upx $(LUA).exe $(LUAC).exe lua53.dll

################################################################################
```

Comment: Thanks, I will make a note of this thread in my personal Lua resource file. My initial use of Lua will be for creating Wikipedia templates, and they are at v. 5.1. Therefore, the binaries I found at https://code.google.com/archive/p/luaforwindows/ are sufficient for the time being.